# Change text color with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, button, colors, onclick

I want to change the color of a title when a button is clicked.
This is my code, but it's not working and I can't figure out why not...

```js
var about;   
function init() { 
    about = document.getElementById("about").innerHTML;
    about.style.color = 'blue';
}
```

```html
<div id="about">About Snakelane</div>
 
<input type="image" src="http://www.blakechris.com/snakelane/assets/about.png" onclick="init()" id="btn">
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You set the style per element and not by its content:

```
function init() { 
  document.getElementById("about").style.color = 'blue';
}
```

With `innerHTML` you get/set the content of an element. So if you would want to modify your title, `innerHTML` would be the way to go.

In your case, however, you just want to modify a property of the element (change the color of the text inside it), so you address the `style` property of the element itself.

Answer (score 8):

use ONLY

```
function init() { 
    about = document.getElementById("about");
    about.style.color = 'blue';
}
```

`.innerHTML()` sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants., All you need is an object here.

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/aQc9Z/)

Answer (score 4):

Try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#about').css({'background-color':'black'});    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jPCFC/

Comment: No mentioning of jQuery anywhere in the question. The function also is in the `onclick` handler of the `<input>` element and not in some `onload` event of the document.

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` is a string representing the contents of the element.

You want to modify the element itself. Drop the `.innerHTML` part.