# How to change the text color with button click?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text like following :

```
<p><strong><em> QUESTION: WHAT IS YOUR NAME?</em></strong></p>
<button>COLORCHANGER<button>
```

I want to change the text color when I click the button.

Comment: What have you try to achieve color change? Show some code that you wrote to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925577/change-text-color-with-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925577/change-text-color-with-javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach `click` event to the button using `addEventListener('click')` then change the color of your text using `.style.color = 'color'`, check example below.

**NOTE :** It will be better if you give your elements an identifier.

Hope this helps.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.querySelector('p').style.color='green';
})
```

```html
<p><strong><em> QUESTION: WHAT IS YOUR NAME?</em></strong></p>
<button>COLORCHANGER</button>
```

Comment: Be careful there's no jquery tag in the OP.

Comment: dear it also one type of JS, build on top of javascript

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to find the element that you want to change colors for by using `document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];` and store it in a variable.

Next, use an event listener on the button element to listen for a click.

When the click executes, the `p` element will change its color to blue.

```js
var colorChanger = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
colorChanger.addEventListener("click",function() {
  document.querySelector('p').style.color = "blue";  
});
```

```html
<p><strong><em> QUESTION: WHAT IS YOUR NAME?</em></strong></p>
 <button>COLORCHANGER<button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click",function() {
  document.querySelector('p').style.color = "red";  
});
```

```html
 <p id = 'textToChange'><strong><em> QUESTION: WHAT IS YOUR NAME?</em></strong></p>
 <button>COLORCHANGER<button>
```

Comment: jQuery was not specified as a framework being used - although nothing was having said that...

Answer (score 1):

```js
function changeColor(){
var element = document.getElementById("questionContainer");
element.className = "myClass";
}
```

```css
.myClass{
 color:red; 
 }
```

```html
<div id="questionContainer"> 
<p><strong><em> QUESTION: WHAT IS YOUR NAME?</em></strong></p>
  </div>
 <button onclick="changeColor()">COLORCHANGER<button>
```

Answer (score 0):

specify id/class to element for better result.

```
       $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
            $("p").css("color", "red");
        });
```