# Changing font colour of string value

Tags: javascript, html, string, styles

Can't work out how to change the color of this with out placing a color attribute in the tag. I want to change the color of the word `"Correct!"`

```
if (Number(array1[i].value) == ((i+1) * number)){
    array2[i].innerHTML = "Correct!";
}
```

Comment: what about array2[i].innerHTML = "<span style='color: red'>Correct!</span>";

Comment: ChrisLi you're a bloody legend mate!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change text color with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925577/change-text-color-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this?

```
array2[i].style.color = "blue";
```