# How to change color of a piece of text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

At first, I apologize for such a basic question, but I'm really new to javascript and I needed to change the color of a script's loading percentage.

The script snippet is this one:

```
function showProgressMessage(e) {
  $('#progress').removeClass('red-text').html(e);
}

showProgressMessage(fileName + ": Loading: " + Math.floor(100 * cnt / end) + "%");
```

How do I change the color of `Math.floor(100 * cnt / end) + "%"`?

Comment: did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925577/change-text-color-with-javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap that part of the text inside a `<span>` that has its CSS color property set.

```js
showProgressMessage(fileName + ": Loading: <span style='color: green;'>" 
                       + Math.floor(100 * cnt / end) + "%</span>");
```

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know how to handle a <span> within javascript.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you.

```
showProgressMessage(fileName + ": Loading: <span style='color: blue;'>" + Math.floor(100 * cnt / end) + "%</span>");
```

Comment: Hey Roger, thanks a lot for the help too!

Answer (score 1):

you can also use color Hex RGB, Example for green color using #008000

```
showProgressMessage(fileName + ": Loading: <span style='color: #008000;'>" + Math.floor(100 * cnt / end) + "%</span>");
```